# Variance for exponential smoothing

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, anova, variance, exponential-smoothing

I want to obtain the analytical expression of variance for simple exponential smoothing . Please help verify and see if the expression could be further simplified , thanks .

Assume the discrete time process $(D_i)_{1 \le i\le t}$ is i.i.d , $(\hat{D}_i)_{1 \le i\le t}$ is the predictor .

The standard practice is to define the first smoothing factor as ,
$$ \hat{D}_1 =    D_1  $$
Let $T_a \ge 0 $ . Observe for t > 1 ,
$$  \hat{D}_t =  \left( \frac{1}{1+T_a} \right) D_t  + \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+T_a} \right) \hat{D}_{t-1}$$
$$  \hat{D}_t = \left( \frac{1}{1+T_a} \right) D_t + \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+T_a} \right)
\left(  \left( \frac{1}{1+T_a} \right) D_{t-1} +\left(  1 - \frac{1}{1+T_a}   \right)
 \left( ...      \right)    \right)$$
expanding out , and pulling out common term
$$ \hat{D}_t =  \left( \frac{1}{1+T_a} \right) \left[ D_t +  \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+T_a}   \right) D_{t-1} +
 \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+T_a}   \right)^2  D_{t-2} +  ... + 
\left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+T_a}    \right)^{t-2}  D_{t-(t-2)}   \right]  $$
$$ +   \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+T_a}    \right)^{t-1} D_1 $$
Then , by i.i.d property
$$ Var(\hat{D_t}) = \left(\frac{1}{1+T_a} \right)^2
\left[   1 +   \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+T_a}   \right)^2 +  \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+T_a}   \right)^4 + ... +
 \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+T_a}    \right)^{2(t-2)} \right] Var(D)
 $$
$$ +   \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+T_a}    \right)^{2(t-1)} Var(D) $$
Since $ 0 \le 1 - \frac{1}{1+T_a}  < 1 $ , by formula for GP series
$$  Var(\hat{D_t})  =   \left\{   \left( \frac{1}{1+T_a} \right)^2
 \left[ \frac{1 - \left(1-  \frac{1}{1+T_a} \right)^{2  (t-1)}  }{1 -  \left( 1- \frac{1}{1+T_a} \right)^2  }  \right]
 +  \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+T_a}   \right)^{2(t-1)}  \right\}  Var(D)  $$

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{M} q^{n} = {1 - q^{M+1} \over 1 - q}$, $0 \leq q \leq 1$, might help with simplification.

Answer (score 2):

Hi: Suppose that you have the following exponential smoothing model where the data, $y_t$, has variance $\sigma^2_y$ :

$\tilde y_t = (1-\lambda) \tilde y_{t-1} + \lambda y_t$.

Then it can be shown that $\sigma^2_{\tilde{y}_{t}} = \left(\frac{\lambda}{2-\lambda}\right) \sigma^2_y$.

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Var}(\tilde y_t) & = \mathrm{Var}((1-\lambda) \tilde y_{t-1} + \lambda y_t) \\
\mathrm{Var}(\tilde y_t) & = (1-\lambda)^2 \mathrm{Var}(\tilde y_{t-1}) + \lambda^2 \mathrm{Var}(y_t) \\
& \vdots
\end{align*}
$$

The proof is on page 72 of Box and Luceno's "Statistical Control by Monitoring and Feedback Adjustment".

Comment: Useful formula , but is it  $\sigma_{\tilde{y}_\infty}^2$  instead ?

Comment: Hi: it's the variance for the one step ahead forecast so I think the subscript using $t$ is more appropriate but I guess you could think of it as $\sigma^2_{\tilde{y}_\infty}$ if that works for you. The derivation is clever but not long. If you want me to write it out, let me know and I'll try to find time this weekend.

Comment: I've seen the derivation in the book you referenced , an infinite sum is used . But do you think the above variance formula is acceptable as long as  t is not too small ?

Comment: Hi: I'm not clear on what the problem is with an infinite sum ?  I'm sure that that formula is correct and it's not dependent on having an infinite # of observations if that is your question ? I didn't go through your derivation but I suggest you use the formula from Box and Luceno. As I said,  the formula does not require an unusually large amount of observations.

Comment: I believe there is a little mistake in the exponent on the fraction. I looked the book up. On the referenced page, they present the equation for standard deviation, where the fraction has an exponent of $1 \over 2$, so for variance, that becomes an exponent of 1. The derivation was a fun exercise, basically starting with the equation for the IIR (that you gave), then equating both variances, and solving the fixed point. https://chat.openai.com/share/4537f3ea-7d4b-4dcb-890f-3f75a01f5e4c

Comment: Not sure I follow but, if you can explain in more detail, where my mistake is, I'll try to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: my edit to fix this was already approved. unfortunately, this site wouldn't let me suggest so small a change (the exponent), so there's additional math now.

Comment: @Christoph: It would be easier if you showed me what's wrong on page 72 rather than writing all that algebra. ( that would take me forever !!!!!, your efforts are appreciated ). When I have some time ( I don't have any right now ),  I'll take your derivation and substitute $\lambda$ for your $\frac{1}{1+T_{a}}$ and see what I get.