# Calculating the Standard Deviation for EWMA

Tags: standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, biostatistics, exponential-smoothing

I'm building an EWMA chart based on the predicted mortality of patients admitted to hospital. I'm working with some previous R code to calculate the standard deviation of the EWMA which work, but I can't figure out WHY the code works.

Specifically it describes it as:

σ<sub>i</sub> = λ<sup>2</sup> * X<sub>i</sub> * (1-X<sub>i</sub>) + (1-λ)<sup>2</sup> * X<sub>i</sub> * σ <sub>i-1</sub>

where
λ = weight,
X = predicted mortality,
σ = SD.

The output seems to be appropriate but I can't find any resources to support it. Wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't know how easy it is to show the equivalence of it with your expression but the closed form solution for the variance  of the EWMA is discussed here. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/572437/variance-for-exponential-smoothing/572485#572485